# VB displaying a specific value in data table according to value in database

Tags: vb.net

Currently I have displayed database values from database to a data table, but now what I need is when my database value is **-1**, it should be displaying at the data table **"N.A Manual Submission"**, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the sql query like this:

```
sql = "SELECT column1, column2, IF(column4 = -1, 'N.A Manual Submission', column4) FROM table;"
```